# JavaScript - passing string as an object property

Tags: javascript

Just FYI this code is part of ExtJS 4 script. I have a global setting which I use to show the path to the dir where my icons are. I'm making some modifications so before was:

> g_settings.iconUrl

but now I need to pass a third argument property like this:

> g_settings.iconUrl.docIcon

The problem I met is where I have an `if` statement where I check for different values:

> if (extensions == 'doc'||extensions == 'docx'||extensions == 'xlsx'||extensions == 'xls)

and then I do:

> extensions += 'Icon';

and I need to use:

> g_settings.iconUrl.extension

when I use `console.log(extensions)` it's value is as expected (for example `docIcon`) but when I try to use it as a property it doesn't work. If I use console.log on:

> console.log(g_settings.iconUrl+ '.' +extensions)

the output is `[object Object].docIcon` so I think I have to convert somehow `extensions` to object too.
I'm not sure that this will solve the problem but that's what I have for now.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Leron

Comment: Was `g_settings.iconUrl` a string before?

Comment: the output is [object Object].docIcon -> this is in my main post. I think that this means that those two were objects. Correct me if i've read the console.log output wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add it to the string..

`console.log("g_settings.iconUrl." + examples)`

Answer (score 0):

iconURL was (and probably still is) a string, but then you added some properties... so on the assignment of .iconURL="..." you should use

```
iconURL.file="...";//(or other name you choose)
```

and latter use

```
.iconURL.file+"."+extensions;
```